# data compression in microcontrollers (DSPIC33E)

Tags: compression, microcontroller

How do I compress data in an MCU?

The MCU has an ADC which logs voltage, current and time stamps
It is supposed to save this to a ram and when the ram is full, send it an off board memory (SD Card)

To maximize the data sent, it is required that we compress the data
the data is in this format

[YY][MM][DD][HH][MM][SS][Voltage][Current]

Assume each box value is 8 bits, so all together, there are 64 bits per data log
More than 1000 data logs will be collected

What is the best way to compress this and prevent redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

Since the difference between two data set is very limited - you are better off recording only deltas i.e. the difference of the current value from the previous. Only at the begining - record a full value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting data every second then you don't need to keep recording the time. Write the first time value then you can assume that each subsequent value was recorded 1 second later.